# PowerShell script which copies a file to remote PC list

Tags: powershell

I tried to copy a file from my pc to a list of remote PCs. I made this PowerShell script, but I receive the follow error when the script running

> "Copy-Item : Access is denied" .

```
$Pclist = Get-Content "D:\pclist.txt"
$username = "adminuser"
$password = "pass"
$FileLocation = 'D:\location.exe'
$Destination = "d$\"
foreach ($_ in $Pclist)
{Copy-Item $FileLocation -Destination \\$_\$Destination -Recurse -PassThru}
```

Comment: Elevate the instance of Powershell ISE/Command Prompt to an Administrator.  Please take the time to edit your question and properly format the code.

Answer (score 1):

Before doing anything else, make sure that there isn't something dodgy happening with your syntax by running the command with hard coded values:

```
Copy-Item 'D:\location.exe' -Destination \\Computer1\D$\ -Recurse -PassThru
```

Without seeing your full error message, I'm not sure if you're getting access denied on your local machine or the remote machine(s).

Assuming it's your local machine, elevate your prompt (run it as an administrator). I normally don't see this issue when pulling from a drive other than 'C' so I'm not 100% sure this is the problem you're having.

You *could* be finding that the account you're running doesn't have permission to write to/access to remote machines. It looks like you've started to specify a username and password there, but you're not actually using it yet.

In order to get a credential object that you can then use with `Copy-Item` consider the following:

```
$username = "adminuser"
$password = "pass"
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username, ($password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force)
```

Note that this will leave the password in plain text in your script for anyone to see, I personally would prefer to do this:

```
$username = "adminuser"
$cred = Get-Credential $username
```

This will pop up a Windows Security dialog with the username pre-populated and ask you to enter the password.

[image: Credential request dialog]

You can then use the `$cred` with other commands, as such:

```
Copy-Item $FileLocation -Destination \\$_\$Destination -Credential $cred -Recurse -PassThru
```

I should point out that this won't protect your credentials. As long as that $cred object exists, it is possible to pull the password out of it in plan text (`$cred.GetNetworkCredential().password`).